# DB2: DROP and CREATE procedures works, CREATE OR REPLACE Not

Tags: db2, procedure, ddl

I'm trying to replace a existing procedure. I want to use CREATE OR REPLACE because I don't want to lose the privileges for this procedures (otherwise I have to set these privileges manually).

But the CREATE OR REPLACE is not working. If I use a DROP and afterwards a CREATE it works fine. Which privilege must a user have to recreate a procedure (recreator is not creator of the procedure)?

Comment: It's hard to help if you report just `not working`. What's exact error message you get on `CREATE OR REPLACE`?

Answer (score 1):

If the question is on privileges needed for the `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE`, then you should look at the following link:
[CREATE PROCEDURE (SQL) statement](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0008329.html)

> To replace an existing procedure, the authorization ID of the
>   statement must be the owner of the existing procedure (SQLSTATE
>   42501).